# Solve matrix equation

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have this 4x4 Matrix to which I apply the `Solve` function:

```
A = FullSimplify[Solve[Aux == 0, {r10, r20, r30}]]
```

Essentialy, it has just 3 independent inputs, which define a system of 3 equations and 3 variables:

```
(c30 - r30)/4==0
1/4 (c10 (-1 + p)^2 - c20 (-1 + p)^2 - r10 + r20)==0
1/4 (c10 (-1 + p)^2 + c20 (-1 + p)^2 - r10 - r20)==0
```

I got the solution:

```
{{r10 -> c10 (-1 + p)^2, r20 -> c20 (-1 + p)^2, r30 -> c30}}
```

Which is perfect.

But when I define the values of `c10`, `c20` and `c30`, for example:

```
 c10=0.1 ; c20=0.1 ; c30=0.9
```

The solve command returns:

```
{}
```

I did the calculations on paper and there is a well defined result. Also I tried to put the equations inside the `Solve` function and it also gives the correct result. Which is the problem???

Comment: Unanswerable if you don't give us the expression for `Aux`.

Comment: Ok, here it goes!

Answer (score 2):

```
eqns = {(c30 - r30)/4 == 0,
   1/4 (c10 (-1 + p)^2 - c20 (-1 + p)^2 - r10 + r20) == 0, 
   1/4 (c10 (-1 + p)^2 + c20 (-1 + p)^2 - r10 - r20) == 0};

sol = Solve[eqns, {r10, r20, r30}][[1]] // Simplify

(* {r10 -> c10 (-1 + p)^2, r20 -> c20 (-1 + p)^2, r30 -> c30} *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
And @@ (eqns /. sol)

(* True *)

values = {c10 -> 0.1, c20 -> 0.1, c30 -> 0.9} // Rationalize;
```

Solving with the assigned `values`

```
sol2 = Solve[eqns /. values, {r10, r20, r30}][[1]] // Simplify

(* {r10 -> 1/10 (-1 + p)^2, r20 -> 1/10 (-1 + p)^2, r30 -> 9/10} *)
```

`sol2` is identical to that given by `sol` with the `values` inserted

```
sol2 === (sol /. values)

(* True *)
```

To verify `sol2` the `eqns` must use the assigned `values` either before or after `sol2` is used

```
And @@ (eqns /. values /. sol2)

(* True *)

And @@ (eqns /. sol2 /. values)

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your seeked solutions and you want to assign the values to the constants `c10`, `c20` and `c30`, just use replacement rules:

```
sol = {{r10 -> c10 (-1 + p)^2, r20 -> c20 (-1 + p)^2, r30 -> c30}};
sol /. {c10 -> 0.1, c20 -> 0.1, c30 -> 0.3}

(* {{r10 -> 0.1 (-1 + p)^2, r20 -> 0.1 (-1 + p)^2, r30 -> 0.9}} *)
```

Comment: I think you forgot some code

Comment: Oh, well spotted !! Sorry for my previous comment :)  (deleted at once!!)...Now, my answer is corrected.

Comment: c30 -> 0.9, not 0.3

Answer (score 0):

Working with MMA 8.0, there are no problems. Clear all parameter definitions like that:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
c10 = 0.1; c20 = 0.1; c30 = 0.9;
sol=FullSimplify[First@Solve[{(c30 - r30)/4 == 0,
   1/4 (c10 (-1 + p)^2 - c20 (-1 + p)^2 - r10 + r20) == 0, 
   1/4 (c10 (-1 + p)^2 + c20 (-1 + p)^2 - r10 - r20) == 0}, {r10, r20,
   r30}]]

(*   {r10 -> (0.316228- 0.316228 p)^2, 
      r20 -> (0.316228- 0.316228 p)^2, r30 -> 0.9}   *)
```

**Edit:**
Expand shows, this is the same result as at the other answers:

```
sol // Expand

(*   {r10 -> 0.1- 0.2 p + 0.1 p^2, 
      r20 -> 0.1- 0.2 p + 0.1 p^2, r30 -> 0.9}   *)

{{r10 -> 0.1 (-1 + p)^2, r20 -> 0.1 (-1 + p)^2, r30 -> 0.9}} // Expand

(*   {{r10 -> 0.1- 0.2 p + 0.1 p^2, 
       r20 -> 0.1- 0.2 p + 0.1 p^2, r30 -> 0.9}}   *)
```

Comment: To @José Antonio Díaz Navas. My answer is not wrong. Do `//Expand `and you get the same as yours. See Edit. Please check this before making changes.

Comment: No problem. Your code did not give your result, but mine in MMA 11.3. Anyway, the OP wants substitute values when getting the general solution, not a particular one.

Comment: The OP already has a general solution. When he defines definite values, he has problems with the solve command, as he told.